# Nginx error too many redirects - node.js + sockets.io + express.js

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am trying to get nginx setup with node.js, sockets.io and express.js. The express.js is listening on port 3000, I have attached sockets.io to the same express object.

I am getting browser error "too many redirects". It looks like its bouncing between (http -> https)?. I have attached my code. However, what I've noticed is that if I comment out my rewrite rule on line 8 - it doesn't give me the error anymore. However what it does is it loads the default nginx index.html instead of my intended nodejs server (localhost:3000). What am I doing wrong here?

/etc/nginx/sites-available/exampledomain.conf :

```
upstream upstream-nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        listen                  80;
        server_name             example.com www.example.com;
        rewrite                 ^(.*)   https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen                  443 ssl;

        ssl                     on;
        server_name             example.com www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; 

        keepalive_timeout       60;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;

        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

        location / {
                proxy_pass              http://upstream-nodejs;
                proxy_next_upstream     error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_redirect          off;
                proxy_buffering         off;

                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                add_header              Front-End-Https         on;
        }

        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_pass              http://upstream-nodejs;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection              "upgrade";

                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Here is my sample node.js code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('GET detected.');
  res.send("Hello World!");
});

const port = 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

The get function never gets called during the "Too many redirects" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a CloudFlare issue. The code above works. For CloudFlare, you need to set under the "Crypto" area, to use Full SSL mode. Also I did the http to https redirect option on as well.

This seems to have fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with CloudFlare as well, but I had to disable the "Proxy Status" setting in the DNS settings.